# Can pedals not fit the crankset?

Tags: parts, pedals, crankset

I just ordered and received my bike with FSA Tempo CK-200 crankset and Shimano Saint MX80 pedals (really good deal).

Just received and it seems that they do not fit with crankset! The spindle on pedals is too big. I probably could forcefully put them on, however i believe I would break stuff.

Before ordering i read online and it seemed that all new bikes (road/cyclocross) have the same size and it should fit just perfect.

It does not. What size do i need? I tried googling FSA Tempo CK-200, but I cannot find any information!

Help!

Comment: You do known there is a right and a left?

Comment: I know, but it seems the crankset and pedal spindle do not fit! Is that even possible?

Comment: Really odd.  Pedals are pretty standard.   Try pedals on another bike to decide which is odd.

Comment: okey, appearantly i was very gentle (new bike). Actually they fit, but i needed to add some power to turn first few rounds!

Comment: Note that the left pedal is opposite threaded while the right pedal is regular threaded.

Comment: @Batman Note that is the first comment and OP replied I know.

Comment: Knowing there are left and right pedals doesn't imply knowing the two pedals have different threading.

Comment: Most likely, what was going on was that there was some surface finish or manufacturing residue on threads of the crank arms. Whatever was there took up just enough space to make it a tight fit and you were, reasonably, cautious enough to go slow and ask questions. Another possibility is that the tap that cut the threads on the crank (or the die on the pedals) was slightly worn and the size is just a little off. A good practice when you're working with something like this is to tighten a bit and then back off before going forward again – and use grease or oil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure? Pedal size is pretty standard.  There is a right and a left.  If you are worried about marring up threads maybe start on the back side.  And grease the threads.

Comment: Yea, that what I actually did, i put some more grease and had to use a bit of force for first few rounds, then it went smoothly.

Comment: @nerijusgood - If you had to use force there's a good chance that you damaged something, sad to say.

Comment: @DanielRHicks Soooo sad to say

Answer (score 1):

There are two common sizes of pedal thread.

- 9/16" which is used for most bikes
- 1/2" which is often found on kids bikes

Doubtless there will be the few oddballs with a metric thread as well, but they'll be really uncommon.